# Dynamically calling function inside SLOT

Tags: c++, qt, function, parameter-passing, slot

I would like to send functions dinamically to SLOT - The idea is to have the same button setup (make code reuse) but with different handlers:

Function call:

```
    buttonSetup(loginButton, "Login", 100, 200, 100, 25, &KHUB::handleLogin);
    buttonSetup(registerButton, "Register", 225, 200, 100, 25, &KHUB::handleRegister);
```

Function setup:

```
    void KHUB::buttonSetup(QPushButton *button, const QString name, int posX, int posY, int width, int height, void(KHUB::*fptr)())
{
    button = new QPushButton(name, this);
    button->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(posX, posY), QSize(width, height)));

    //Event Listener
    connect(button, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(fptr));
}
```

I was trying to pass the function as a parameter and acquire its name based on the pointer (which doesn't represent exactly how the code is disposed here), but I'm not sure if this is the best solution or even a solution. Does anyone know if that is possible to do and how am I able to do this?

**Edited as pointed by @Slyps [Working Code]:**

Function call:

```
    buttonSetup(&loginButton, "Login", 100, 200, 100, 25, &KHUB::handleLogin);
    buttonSetup(&registerButton, "Register", 225, 200, 100, 25, &KHUB::handleRegister);
```

Function setup:

```
    void KHUB::buttonSetup(QPushButton **button, const QString name, int posX, int posY, int width, int height, void(KHUB::*fptr)())
{
    *button = new QPushButton(name, this);
    (*button)->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(posX, posY), QSize(width, height)));

    //Event Listener
    connect(*button, &QPushButton::released, this, fptr);
}
```

Comment: On a side node: What exactly is your purpose of the parameter `button` ? You are not getting the address of the newly created QPushButton into the variable `loginButton/registerButton` of the scope in which you call `buttonSetup`. You need to use `**` for that. And if you dont want to use `loginButton/registerButton` in that scope, then the parameter is useless.

Comment: you are right, this was crashing the application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the newer syntax:

```
connect(button, &QPushButton::released, this, fptr);
```

Answer (score 4):

Either use the newer syntax like in ratchetfreaks answer, or, for the traditional syntax:

```
buttonSetup(loginButton, "Login", 100, 200, 100, 25, SLOT(handleLogin));
buttonSetup(registerButton, "Register", 225, 200, 100, 25, SLOT(handleRegister));

void KHUB::buttonSetup(QPushButton *button, const QString name, int posX, int posY, int width, int height, const char * slot)
{
    button = new QPushButton(name, this);
    button->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(posX, posY), QSize(width, height)));

    //Event Listener
    connect(button, SIGNAL(released()), this, slot);
}
```

`SLOT` is just a preprocessor macro that turns its argument into a string and adds a flag wether its `SLOT` or `SIGNAL` ( and debug information in debug mode ). So if you write

```
connect(button, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(fptr));
```

it doesnt pass the content of the variable `fptr`, but merely turns it into text "1fptr", and that slot obviously doesnt exist.